# Mobile Menu - expanding and collapsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have created a responsive mobile menu using jquery. Everything works fine except the toggling of the menu. By default the menu is expanded. I want the menu to be collapsed by default and when the word menu is clicked it expands and is then able to expand and collapse on selection. The only point of consideration in this is that there is also a normal navigation menu, which is displayed and layout differently. I wish for this menu to be always active. I only want the mobile menu to be hidden (collapsed) by default and then expanded on when clicked.

I have uploaded the projected onto jsfiddle: `link`http://jsfiddle.net/qdhg0r9d/

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {    
#collapse-menu{
    display:none;
    }
}
```

To your CSS this will hide it by default when the screen width is less than 600px, then when you click the toggle jQuery will over ride it for you by adding the inline style `display:block;` and display it again

Comment: this affects my normal desktop navigation, by default it doesn't display it. I only want the mobile menu hidden not the desktop one.

Comment: ok well then you just need to add it to a media query which will only kick in when your screen is below a certain size, I updated my answer with an example

Comment: glad it helped you out, feel free to change the `max-width` value in the media query to whatever it is you want, I just took that as an example

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if($(window).width() <= 640){
        $("#collapse-menu").toggle();
        $("#pull").on('click',function () {
            $("#collapse-menu").toggle();
        });   
    }
});
```

it only works depending on the screen width

Comment: can this be done, without affecting the desktop navigation, have it only targeted at the mobile navigation?